# Buscar datos de un array en una matriz PHP

Tags: php, array

Mi problema es el siguiente, por ejemplo, tengo una matriz:

ID - Nombre - Tipo
152 - elemento1 - tipo1
536 - elemento2 - tipo2
85 - elemento3 - tipo3
105 - elemento4 - tipo4

Y tengo un `array`:

```
$busca = array(105,536,85);
```

Lo que necesito es buscar los elementos del `array` en la primera columna de la matriz. Lo intente recorriendo la matriz y comparando con los elementos del `array`, el problema es de que como los elementos están desordenados, solo me da como resultado algunos, no todos.

¿Algún consejo? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Le faltan datos a tu pregunta, no dices lo que quieres como **resultado final**, si comparar simplemente si existe el valor buscado activando una bandera booleana, si introducir en un nuevo array todos los elementos cuando haya coincidencias, si sacar las coincidencias del array original, si... si... Como comprenderás, hay mil formas de hacer esto y según el resultado final que esperes, las respuestas podrían muy distintas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supongamos que tu tabla se llama $array_uno, entonces puedes hacer algo como:

```
        $busca = array(105,536,85);
        $encontrados = [];
        foreach ($array_uno as $item) {
            if (in_array($item->ID, $busca)) {
                array_push($encontrados, $item)
            }
        }
       // Mostrar resultado.
       var_dump($encontrados);
```

En $encontrados se guardaran solo los registros que tengan ID en $busca.

Comment: gracias! resulto de maravilla!!!